# Have an idea for Amazon animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, animation

I am a Flutter beginner. I'm trying to create something that mimics the Amazon UI for study purposes, but I can't figure out how to create an animation like the GIF image attached.
I know that I can use a `Wrap`Widget or a `GridView`Widget and arrange the buttons side by side, but I don't know how to implement an animation where tapping a button after that will cause the button to move down and another widget to appear from the line below.
Any ideas?[image: flutter]

Comment: I'm not a flutter dev, but one idea:  View Source or Inspect in a browser to look at their HTML-CSS-JS code, then search on what you find to see what flutter code will recreate it?   For example if CSS has on hover or click styles, search on how to add those?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple TweenAnimation to make the visibilty of the Widget visible and gone. As for the part where the layout moves down when the widget appears, Flutter will take care of it implicitly.